# Flex: moving a point with rotation doesnt change the point XY?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i have the follow issue :

I have a point which is setted at the border on a component, 
with changed transform point to the center of a component in order to match the component rotation.

the important part is when i try to get the point XY after rotation - they remains the same as before rotation.

[image]

- how to get XY, after rotation ( changeing point.rotation property to specific degrees of rotaion )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the point after rotation, `cos(r) * x, sin(r) * y` is the easiest way.

If you want the point after all transformations, you should be able to use `displayObject.transform.transformPoint(x, y)`.

There's also `DisplayObject.localToGlobal`.  In this case you could call `localToGlobal(x, y)` and `localToGlobal(0, 0)` and calculate the difference.

See [Transform livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html) and [DisplayObject livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Sean's answer. But to add a bit of context: the x,y location of any object on the display list is relative to the container in which it resides. Rotating the container doesn't change the x,y relative position of items within that container.

So if you have a display object representing your point and it is inside a Sprite or MovieClip, then no amount of rotation of the container will change the x,y location of the point DisplayObject.